# Undefined method when I try adding new document under another using belong_to with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to have two documents one for posts and one for replies, and connect them using "Referenced 1-N" relationship.

From what I read from the [mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many), all you have to do is add `has_many` and `belongs_to` into both classes and mongoid will allow me to add child documents that points to the parent.

**So what I want to do simply is**

1. create a new reply document that points to the parent
2. if possible have an array that holds ids of the children

I've tried to access reply from post in all ways and it doesn't work. So it would be great if someone can crack this puzzle for me :)

**Output**

> undefined method 'reply' for #< PostsController: >

**Model**

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :replies
  field :text,:type => String
end

class Reply
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :post
  field :name, :type => String
  field :text, :type => String
end
```

**Controller**

```
def create_reply
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  post.reply.new(params[:post])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reply` is undefined for your `Post` class because `Post` has many `replies`, not `reply`.

Try writing `post.replies.new(params[:post])` in your `create_reply` method instead.

Comment: Thanks, a lot you're a life saver. Is there a way keep an array of children in the paren for easy access?

Comment: Once you've created a child element using that syntax and saved the parent element, the association between the two will be saved. So you'll be able to access all the replies on a post by using `post.replies`, where `post` is an instance of the `Post` class.